# How to keep duplicated "on" column value rows in merge_asof in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames that i want to merge with the merge_asof function but I am facing a small issue.

```
import pandas as pd

radiology_scan = pd.DataFrame({"patient_id":['a001','a002','a003'],
                     "Visit_year": [2010, 2012, 2016], "scan_report": [1, 55,2]})



OPD_data = pd.DataFrame({"patient_id":['a001','a001','a002','a003','a004','a005'],
                      
                      "Visit_year": [2010 , 2010 , 2013, 2017, 2017,2018],
                      
                      "doctor_comments": ['diagnosis normal, xyz symptoms',
                                          'diagnosis normal, abc symptoms',
                                          'diagnosis abnormal, pqr symptoms',
                                          'diagnosis abnormal, apq symptoms',
                                          'diagnosis normal, xzy symptoms',
                                          'diagnosis abnormal, yzx symptoms' ]})


x = pd.merge_asof(radiology_scan, OPD_data, on =  ["Visit_year"], by =   ["patient_id"] , direction="nearest")

# when using merge_asof only the first visit of the a001's OPD is seen in the merged data frame


y = pd.merge(radiology_scan, OPD_data, on =["Visit_year","patient_id" ], how = 'left' )

# merge function gives both visits of the matched visit year , but i cannot merge the nearest visits of other patients whose
# visit years from both the data frames don't match, hence I want to use merge_asof
```

When using the merge_asof function I am unable to retain the value of the 2nd visit of the patient a001 from the OPD-data in the merged data frame, even though the id and the visit year matches. The doctor_comment is different and hence i want to retain it in the merged data frame.

On the other hand while using the merge function I am able to retain it but I cannot asof for other patient's data to match the nearest visit year .

The output that I expect is
[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? You want to match `a001, 2010, 1` with `xyz symptom` and `abc symptom` ? Not able to understand the challenge

Comment: I've provided an answer below.  If you expected different output, the best option is to provide the expected output as part of the question.

Comment: @JoeFerndz I have added the expected output, you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the input order may produce what you want, as `merge_asof` is a  "left join" operation:

```
x = pd.merge_asof(OPD_data, radiology_scan, on=["Visit_year"], by=["patient_id"], direction="nearest")
```

output:

```
  patient_id  Visit_year                   doctor_comments  scan_report
0       a001        2010    diagnosis normal, xyz symptoms          1.0
1       a001        2010    diagnosis normal, abc symptoms          1.0
2       a002        2013  diagnosis abnormal, pqr symptoms         55.0
3       a003        2017  diagnosis abnormal, apq symptoms          2.0
4       a004        2017    diagnosis normal, xzy symptoms          NaN
5       a005        2018  diagnosis abnormal, yzx symptoms          NaN
```

Note that `Visit_year` is taken from `OPD_data` in this case.

Comment: I want the visit_year from the radiology_scan data frame as they are of the prime focus in my study. I want the doctor's comment of the exact visit year or nearest visit year if available. If in some cases there are more than one OPD visits in the same year or nearest year, I want them all from the OPD sheet of that same person.